# ifx macro not behaving as expected

Tags: macros, conditionals, xstring

I am trying the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\FormatName#1{
  \def\myname{My Name}
  \def\name{#1}
  \ifx\name\myname
    \textbf{#1}
  \else
    #1
  \fi
}

\FormatName{My Name}

\FormatName{My Name*}

\end{document}
```

The first call creates My Name in bold font, but not the second. Therefore, if I modify the definition of `\name` as

```
\def\name{\StrDel{#1}{*}}
```

But this does not work for either first or second call. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see whether

```
\ifx<csnameA><csnameB>
  <true>
\else
  <false>
\fi
```

will follow the `<true>` or `<false>` branch, it's always a good idea to issue `\show<csnameA>` and `\show<csnameB>` before to see what they evaluate to. Let's use your first example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\FormatName#1{%
  \def\myname{My Name}%
  \def\name{#1}%
  \show\myname\show\name
  \ifx\name\myname
    \textbf{#1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}

\FormatName{My Name}

\FormatName{My Name*}

\end{document}
```

The `.log` file shows

```
> \myname=macro:
->My Name.

> \name=macro:
->My Name.
```

These are clearly the same. Then it also shows:

```
> \myname=macro:
->My Name.

> \name=macro:
->My Name*.
```

These are clearly difference. Hence, the output is as expected. Now look at your updated setup that uses [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\FormatName#1{%
  \def\myname{My Name}%
  \def\name{\StrDel{#1}{*}}%
  \show\myname\show\name
  \ifx\name\myname
    \textbf{#1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}

\FormatName{My Name}

\FormatName{My Name*}

\end{document}
```

The `.log` shows

```
> \myname=macro:
->My Name.

> \name=macro:
->\StrDel {My Name}{*}.

> \myname=macro:
->My Name.

> \name=macro:
->\StrDel {My Name*}{*}.
```

In both cases, it's clear these entries don't match. Now (again), the output is expected.

---

If you want to delete a `*` from `\name`, you need to fully expand the deletion and use that in the comparison. `xstring` provides this expansion-and-storage as part of most of its string manipulation macros. Specifically for `\StrDel`, add an optional `[<csname>]` at the end:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\FormatName#1{%
  \def\myname{My Name}%
  \StrDel{#1}{*}[\name]%
  \show\myname\show\name
  \ifx\name\myname
    \textbf{#1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}

\FormatName{My Name}

\FormatName{My Name*}

\end{document}
```

---

You can also use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to remove (the first) `*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\FormatName#1{%
  \def\myname{My Name}%
  \def\name{#1}%
  \patchcmd{\name}{*}{}{}{}%
  \show\myname\show\name
  \ifx\name\myname
    \textbf{#1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}

\FormatName{My Name}

\FormatName{My Name*}

\end{document}
```

If you want to remove *all* `*`, one can use [`regexpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/regexpatch).

Comment: Many thanks for such a useful answer! If I may ask a follow up question, is it possible to check the argument against a list/array of strings? For example if I want to highlight several names. If it is a question that deserves a new question, I will be happy to do that.

Comment: @Ankush: I don't understand. Perhaps a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764) is in order.

Answer (score 0):

`\def` does not interpret the replacement text, so testing `My Name` against `\StrDel{My Name*}{*}` will obviously fail.

You can use `expl3` (via `xparse`) and get much more:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setspecialnames}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_ankush_specialnames_seq { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_ankush_specialnames_seq
\tl_new:N \l_ankush_testname_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatName}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_ankush_testname_tl { #1 }
  \tl_remove_all:Nn \l_ankush_testname_tl { * }
  \seq_if_in:NVTF \g_ankush_specialnames_seq \l_ankush_testname_tl
   {
    \textbf{#1}
   }
   {
    #1
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setspecialnames{My Name, A. Uthor}

\begin{document}

\FormatName{My Name} \FormatName{My Name*}

\FormatName{A. Uthor} \FormatName{A. Uthor*}

\FormatName{W. Riter}

\end{document}
```

[image]